# useContext in Action.js (outside of React Component)

Tags: reactjs

Currently I have some state stored in DataContext.js, however, I'd like to access this data from in an Action.js file.

The DataContext is normally pulled with the useContext hook and this is possible since a component is wrapped in DataContextProvider.

However, my Action.js is not a React component (and thus not wrapped in the DataContextProvider). Is there any way I can access the state?

Comment: Could you share some code of what you are trying to do? You can't access a context from outside a react component but I am sure there is a solution for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this by simply passing the state to the Action.js file.

So let's say the is a FindFoo() function in the Action.js file, I called FindFoo(state) in the React component and used the state as a parameter in this function.